# Rails 7 not executing code within controller method on POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a really basic Rails 7 application at the moment. Using all the defaults.

For some reason, Rails is not entering/running the code within a controller I've defined.

Here is the related route.

```rb
scope module: 'admin', path: 'admin', as: 'admin' do
  root 'home#index'
  resources :users do 
    post :invite, on: :collection
  end
end
```

Here is the related Controller method:

```rb
def invite 
  puts "INVITE" * 100
  invite_params = params.require(:admin_invite).permit(:name, :email)
  @invite = Admin::Invite.new(invite_params)
  respond_to do |f|
    if @invite.send_invite
      f.html { redirect_to admin_users_url, notice: "Invite sent" }
    else
      f.html { redirect_to admin_users_url, status: :unprocessible_entity, error: "There was an error sending the invite" }
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the form that POSTs to that route.

```
= form_with model: @new_invite, url: invite_admin_users_url, html: {"data-turbo" => false} do |f|
  = f.label :name
  = f.text_field :name
  = f.label :email
  = f.email_field :email
  = f.submit "Invite"
```

I thought maybe it had something to do with `TURBO` that comes with Rails 7, so I disabled it on this form, but it didn't resolve the issue.

When I click submit on that form, I get the following error: `No template found`.

Looking at the output in the terminal, it seems to be POSTing properly to the controller, but it's not running any of the code with the method. Even that `puts` statement I have at the beginning of the `#invite` method doesn't execute.

```
19:26:14 web.1  | Started POST "/admin/invite_user" for ::1 at 2022-09-07 19:26:14 -0400
19:26:14 web.1  | Processing by Admin::UsersController#invite as HTML
19:26:14 web.1  |   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "admin_invite"=>{"name"=>"Test", "email"=>"test@test.com"}, "commit"=>"Invite"}
19:26:14 web.1  |   User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
19:26:14 web.1  | No template found for Admin::UsersController#invite, rendering head :no_content
```

Any ideas?

Comment: well it's looking for a user... the log says "User Load...". Where is this db query initiated? Is it in the `Admin::Invite.new(invite_params)` method? Anyway it's within the UsersController#invite method. Do you have two #invite methods defined inadvertently?

Comment: Thanks for the input, Les! That's being called by devise via `before_action :authenticate_user!` on the controller. I can disable it for that action, but I don't think that's really the reason why   Rails isn't entering the `invite` method.

Comment: for debugging purposes, disable all before_action filters.

Comment: Thanks, Les. All filters have been disabled now. It's still producing the same result.

Comment: for debugging purposes, make an actual template app/views/admin/users/invite.html with some content like "hello from users#invite" does it render?

Comment: It renders. However, the code that's in the Controller isn't called at all.

Comment: does it create an error if you completely comment-out the #invite method in the controller?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247893/discussion-between-john-and-les-nightingill).

Comment: In case you don't want to chat, it doesn't produce an error after I comment out that method.